# How to split Dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have column value like 1ST:[70]2ND:[71]3RD:[71]S1:[71]4TH:[77]5TH:[78]6TH:[78]S2:[78]FIN:[75] in csv, need to extract all merged content into separate column, how to do it pandas

need O/p like:

```
 1ST 2ND 3RD  S1 4TH 5TH 6TH  S2 FIN
0  70  71  71  71  77  78  78  78  75
```

here i have pasted some of rows of that column value.

```
1ST:[80]2ND:[79]3RD:[75]S1:[78]4TH:[76]5TH:[80]6TH:[87]S2:[81]FIN:[80]
1ST:[75]2ND:[74]3RD:[81]S1:[77]4TH:[80]5TH:[78]6TH:[87]S2:[82]FIN:[80]
1ST:[58]2ND:[54]3RD:[65]S1:[59]4TH:[80]5TH:[72]6TH:[74]S2:[75]FIN:[67]
1ST:[90]2ND:[91]3RD:[82]S1:[88]4TH:[84]5TH:[88]6TH:[87]S2:[86]FIN:[87]
1ST:[83]2ND:[79]3RD:[82]S1:[81]4TH:[85]5TH:[84]6TH:[90]S2:[86]FIN:[84]
```

IN dataframe i have one column contains above value. i need to split into different columns and value will be in rows.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: Please use proper formatting to show a sample of the required output. It'll help us to answer your question quickly and precisely in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems confusing. What is your objective from solution structure side?

your file is having value like this
`1ST:[70]2ND:[71]3RD:[71]S1:[71]4TH:[77]5TH:[78]6TH:[78]S2:[78]FIN:[75]`

you want output should be in this way

```
  1ST 2ND 3RD  S1 4TH 5TH 6TH  S2 FIN
0  70  71  71  71  77  78  78  78  75
```

or like this

```
     0   1
0  1ST  70
1  2ND  71
2  3RD  71
3   S1  71
4  4TH  77
5  5TH  78
6  6TH  78
7   S2  78
8  FIN  75
```

Now, approach to get output from given input

```
import pandas as pd
# consider your input is string (you can use csv)
file_val = "1ST:[70]2ND:[71]3RD:[71]S1:[71]4TH:[77]5TH:[78]6TH:[78]S2:[78]FIN:[75]"

df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(':') for i in file_val.replace('[',"").split(']') if i!=""])
print(df)
     0   1
0  1ST  70
1  2ND  71
2  3RD  71
3   S1  71
4  4TH  77
5  5TH  78
6  6TH  78
7   S2  78
8  FIN  75
```

Please share the snap shot of csv file or couple of rows, so that I could be able to generate the output as per your requirement.

**Coming back to the final solution as per your format**

```
# reading data 
with open('sample.csv') as f:
    dat = file.read(f)

# spliting rows 
dat1 = dat.split(\n)

# method to convert each row to dict
def row_to_dict(row):
    return dict([i.split(":") for i in row.replace('[',"").split(']') if i!=""])

# now apply method to each row of dat1 and create single dataframe out of it 
# that is nothing but final output

res = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x:row_to_dict(x), dat1))

print(res)
  1ST 2ND 3RD 4TH 5TH 6TH FIN  S1  S2
0  80  79  75  76  80  87  80  78  81
1  75  74  81  80  78  87  80  77  82
2  58  54  65  80  72  74  67  59  75
3  90  91  82  84  88  87  87  88  86
4  83  79  82  85  84  90  84  81  86
```

Comment: Need o/p as first one as you mentioned above

Comment: Thanks for sharing the data and required output format... Will send you solution in couple of minutes and please don't forget to put vote on right side of answer

Comment: Thank you, sure will do, waiting for solution

Comment: Hi Ganapati, I have updated the solution below the bold heading.

Answer (score 0):

Find the above result in R

```
a1=read.csv("c:/Users/Dell/Desktop/NewText.txt",header = FALSE)
a1$V1=as.character(a1$V1)
g1=NULL
g2=NULL
l=list()
for(i in 1:nrow(a1))
    {
        g1=strsplit(a1$V1[i],"]")

        g1=strsplit(g1[[1]],":\\[")

          g2=data.frame(g1)
          g2[] <- lapply(g2, as.character)
          colnames(g2)=g2[1,]
          g2=g2[-1,]
          l[[i]]=g2         
}
l=do.call('rbind',l)
```